# How to change Mongodb`s default storage engine(wiredtiger) to my revised wiredtiger(git source build)?

Tags: mongodb, ycsb, wiredtiger, storage-engines

I am going to modify the wiredtiger code to test the ycsb benchmark to improve performance.

Through this wiki doc (https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger/wiki/Btree-vs-LSM), I was able to test the basic wiredtiger code and the modified code at Leveldb.

Next step, I want to use **YCSB** to benchmark my edited wiredtiger code, but I cannot find a way to compare this.

So I setup mongodb to using YCSB benchmark since mongodb using wiredtiger as the storage engine.

**But there is a problem that I don't know how I can change the mongodb`s wiredtiger storage engine(default) to I've modified(git source build).**

I need advice

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
mongod --dbpath 'specify new path' --storageEngine 'your storage engine name'
```